# Biblatex: 1) changing separator, 2) repeating author

Tags: biblatex

(La)TeX newbie here. I'm writing my philosophy thesis in LyX. Loving it so far but trying to hack myself around the limitations of BibTex has been exhausting. Now – finally – I've gotten Biblatex to work in LyX - what a huge relieve! With babel it beautifully renders everything in the bibliography in to my language.

I just have two issues that I hope are easier to resolve now that I'm using Biblatex

I'm using the author-year style with this in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
```

**1. I would like to separate year and cited page with colon instead of comma:**

This:

> Wittgenstein 1961: §4.003, 36

Instead of this:

> Wittgenstein 1961, §4.003, 36

**2. I would like to have the name of an author with multiple works repeated:**

This:

> Wittgenstein, Ludwig (1961). Tractatus Logico Philosophicus. Routledge & Kegan Paul.
>   Wittgenstein, Ludwig (2010). Philosophical Investigations. en. John Wiley & Sons.

Instead of this:

> Wittgenstein, Ludwig (1961). Tractatus Logico Philosophicus. Routledge & Kegan Paul.
>   – (2010). Philosophical Investigations. en. John Wiley & Sons.

Your help is much appreciated. I'm hoping that I soon will be able to spend more time on actually writing my thesis than familiarizing myself with TeX :)

Comment: Use the `dashed=false` package option and add the following to your preamble: `\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}`. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles

Comment: Please, note that you don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! My questions were answered in the comments thusly:

**Ad. 1.**

```
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
```

Also if you want to remove "p." after the colon add:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
```

**Ad. 2.**
Add `dashed=false` to `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}`